# Allowoverride All in shared hosting

Tags: php, linux, apache, .htaccess, hosting

I am using hostgator Linux shared hosting. i want to Allowoverride All using .htaccess file

**base url -** */home/domain_name/public_html*

when i try to do

```
<Directory /home/domain_name>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Its throw 500 internal server error

Comment: You cannot do that is a `.htaccess` style file. That is the whole point: to allow to do that in the _real_ configuration. Take a loko at the documentation, I suggest.

Comment: As i mention, i have shared hosting hostgator not give me access of apache. So is this any other way to do that. i want to use SLIM framwork there.

Comment: No, there is no other way. This makes sense. The _whole point_ of the `AllowOverride` command is to grant or deny what settings can be overridden. If your hosting provider chooses not to grant certain things, then there is nothing you can simply do to "work around that". That would be a security nightmare if you were able to. So the bottom line is: if you require such flexibility, then move to a better hosting provider that _does_  offer what you need, or, even more flexible, get an own VPS.

Answer (score 0):

The 500 error is because [`Directory`](https://devdocs.io/apache_http_server/mod/core#directory) directive is allowed only in 2 contexts, namely: server config and virtual host config.

Do go through [this document](https://devdocs.io/apache_http_server/sections) on the different types of configuration sections available in Apache.

Answer (score 0):

If you take share hosting and your apache version is greater then 2.4

Go to all .htaccess (your_magento_setup/.htaccess, pub/.htaccess)
then you just comment this tag fully in your both htaccess.

```
<IfVersion >= 2.4>
```

Your magento 2 setup working properly.